# Allowed memory Size exhausted, when sending array for delete

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is a fragment of my HTML:

```
<td>
<?php 
echo '&nbsp'. anchor('hrd/terima/'.$b->noDaftar, 'Proses', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm','onclick'=>"return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin Menerima Lamaran Ini?')"));
echo '&nbsp'. anchor('hrd/tolak/'.$b->noDaftar, 'Tolak', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm','onclick'=>"return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin Menolak Lamaran Ini?')"));
?>
</td>
```

And this is my controller function to 'Tolak':

```
function tolak($noDaftar){
$data=$this->M_hrd->lamaranMasuk2();
$foto=$data->pathFoto;
$ktp=$data->pathKtp;
$ijazah=$data->pathIjazah;
$surat=$data->pathSurat;
$nilai=$data->pathNilai;
if ($this->M_hrd->cekFoto2($noDaftar)==TRUE){
    unlink("lamaran/".$foto);
}

$this->M_hrd->lamaranDitolak($noDaftar);
echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>window.alert('CV Telah Ditolak')window.location.href='http://www.hondamugen.co.id/hrd';
</script>");
}
```

Lastly, this is my model:

```
function lamaranDitolak($noDaftar)
{
    $this->db->delete('data_pekerjaan', array('noDaftar'=>$noDaftar));
    $this->db->delete('data_referensi', array('noDaftar'=>$noDaftar));
    $this->db->delete('data_pertanyaan', array('noDaftar'=>$noDaftar));
}
```

The error appeared when I added unlink function to the controller. Can you tell me what's wrong? Google says the solution is to increase memory limit of php.ini, but I was just wondering what is wrong? If we could send just data of list an array could possibly cause this error?